# Google Fonts doesn't load in mobile

Tags: css, mobile, fonts

I've read similiar threads but this problem is a bit different: I have:

```
<head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
//rest of the code...
```

And in the css style file I have:

```
body{
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    //rest of the code...
```

It works perfectly in the browser, but when I enter with my mobile, the words just dissapear, and the page is loding forever with only the structure. I'm still developing the webpage, so I was trying it with the mobile to check everything works.

1.- I've tried `@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/....` and nothing.

2.- I've changed the font to Arial in the css file and it works.

3.- My mobile is Nexus 4 with chrome.

4.- I've tried with another font of Google Api and nothing.

5.- It works perfect in the desktop browser. Even in IE.

Anyone knows what could be the problem? Thank you!

Comment: I'm guessing you've checked your Chrome browser on your mobile for any settings that force a font or prevent remote font loading? (Not sure if they have such a setting, but worth checking.) Also, is this over WiFi or your mobile data plan? There shouldn't be a difference, but it may help narrow your field of investigation.

Comment: I'm using Wifi, and I have configured the phone to accept everything except popups. I have another webpage with an external font, and it works in my mobile, but I have in the css @font-face{ scr:url(.... eto,woff,ttf and svg. The problem is just with this Api of Google.

Comment: Is the app you're trying to hit (the one that hosts the font-face link, above) behind SSL by any chance? That's about the only other thing I can think of that might be causing the issue. Have you tried commenting out all your other CSS, and only leaving in the body {} spec to see if it still refuses to see Google's custom font?

Comment: Yep, I have tried many things, one of them, that one. Leaving the body alone, eliminating all the rest css files, etc etc.. I'm not behind SSL. It's really annoying, and I'm the kind of person who try to solve something by himself... but sometimes I'm completely lost!

Comment: At a /really/ long shot, here, could you check to make sure that your WiFi setting doesn't have a proxy enabled? I don't know why, but every now and then my wifi settings add a proxy into place that causes weird things to happen when loading my pages. Outside of that, unfortunately, I wish you luck, as I'm really unsure what else could be going on. :/

Comment: Same [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35964869/google-font-is-not-displayed-in-android-browser-5-0-1-how-to-fix). I haven't found a solution either. It works perfectly in every browser (including Chrome for Android), except the default Android 5.0.1 browser with empty cache. Have you found a solution yet?