# Google Font is not displayed in Android Browser (5.0.1). How to fix?

Tags: android, html, css

The code below works perfectly in Chrome, Chrome for Android, Edge, IE11, Firefox, Opera etc. The only compatibility issue I've found is on Android 5.0.1 using the default browser on a Samsung Galaxy S4. Is it a known bug? Is there a known fix?

The problem is that no text is displayed, I see a blank page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style>
body {font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;}  
@media only screen and (min-width:1px) and (max-width:2px) {}   
</style>
</head>
<body>Lorem ipsum.</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It happens only if the cache is flushed. On reload, it works perfectly.

Comment: I'm thinking about serving the fonts from my own server, but I'd prefer Google CDN if possible.

Comment: Sorry, duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20842381/google-fonts-doesnt-load-in-mobile